# How can I get Yahoo Weather Backgrounds from API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yahoo-api, yahoo-weather-api

I have a weather widget, and I need dynamic backgrounds. Yahoo has weather APIs, but I'm not able to find the background image tied to a weather type. https://weather.yahoo.com/ Is this possible?

```
var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%3D%2248907%22&format=json'
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            })
```

Comment: they provide the data.... how you display it is up to you. You would need to parse results to manage your own image displays

Comment: Show me where the background images are in the results? I don't believe they are there.

Answer (score 3):

The API doesn't provide any images, but you can use a lot of the data to provide an image yourselves. Use for example the following properties

```
condition":{"code":"34", ...  // here you can bind an image to the code
```

Then you have a wind object

```
wind":{
  "chill":"55",       // thermometer?
  "direction":"0",     // use an image or a canvas to draw an arrow dynamically
  "speed":"0"
}, ...
```

and an atmosphere object

```
"atmosphere":{
  "humidity":"51",     // some drops?
  "pressure":"30.4",   // textual..
  "rising":"2",
  "visibility":"10"    // textual..
}, ...
```

And so on. As you can see there are many ways to illustrate these data but it's entirely up to you how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but there is no API for this.
But you can access their backgrounds by viewing the network activity on your browser developer tools.

The best solution is to build your own Api with your own images,

This is a sample of there background url:

https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/weather/images/fallbacks/lead/clear_n-e618500.jpg